# Is it possible to "semi-maximize left or right" in LXDE in any way?

Tags: desktop-environments, lxde

I mean like in Unity when you drag a window and stick it to the *"right"*, it first shows a shadow covering the right half of the desktop and then the window would cover that half on mouse release.

Is it possible to do that on LXDE? Not at all necessarily by dragging the window; a keyboard shortcut would be great! Any way at all would be great.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using LXDE, it still depends on the window manager. The usual default window manager is Openbox. Openbox keyboard tricks are listed here:  **http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions**

Each distro offering LXDE comes with its own list of actions. In Lubuntu 13.10, which is the LXDE flavor with Openbox as window manager, you have the settings here:
**/home/user/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml**

And a part of which maybe relevant to you is this:

> ```
> <!-- Keybindings for window tiling -->
> <keybind key="W-Left">        # HalfLeftScreen
>   <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
>   <action name="MoveResizeTo">
>     <x>0</x><y>0</y>
>     <height>97%</height>
>     <width>50%</width>
>   </action>
> </keybind>
> <keybind key="W-Right">        # HalfRightScreen
>   <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
>   <action name="MoveResizeTo">
>     <x>-0</x><y>0</y>
>     <height>97%</height>
>     <width>50%</width>
>   </action>
> </keybind>
> <keybind key="W-Up">        # HalfUpperScreen
>   <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
>   <action name="MoveResizeTo">
>     <x>0</x><y>0</y>
>     <width>100%</width>
>     <height>50%</height>
>     </action>
> </keybind>
> <keybind key="W-Down">        # HalfLowerScreen
>   <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
>   <action name="MoveResizeTo">
>     <x>0</x><y>-0</y>
>     <width>100%</width>
>     <height>50%</height>
>     </action>
> </keybind>
> ```

There is also a mouse-based method but I think it is not available by default. You will need [Opensnap ppa](https://github.com/lawl/opensnap). Check if it is available for your *buntu version.

I don't know about the shadow effect.

Comment: wow!! thanks!! looks like it'd work but I'm having issues. I can't edit the file. I think because it doesn't exist. I don't know. I used gedit and it displays an error. what do I do?

Comment: no no it's okay; I have Openbox. ... I typed in this command `gksudo gedit /home/user/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml` so it opened gedit and I pasted the script but when I try saving it just displays an error

Comment: in /usr/share/xsessions I see all desktop environments I've installed including LXDE and openbox

Comment: I have a question; what does `~/` mean? home? (I'm talking about `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`)

Comment: Gnome, Gnome Classic, GNOME Flashback, GNOME Flashback (No effects), GNOME/Openbox, KDE/Openbox, LXDE, Openbox, Ubuntu. ...That was all what's in /usr/share/xsessions.

Comment: okay that's one valuable hint (about the ~) ... In openbox I have lxde-rc.xml ... that's what I'm supposed to edit?

Comment: GREAT YOU JUST TOLD ME THAT! I was about to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using LXDE and I had success changing **~/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml** with the xml below.
This makes the semi-maximize (left/right) to arrange side by side like in Ms windows.

```
<keybind key="W-Left">
   <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
   <action name="MaximizeVert"/>     
   <action name="MoveResizeTo">
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width client="yes">1/2</width>
   </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="W-Right">
   <action name="UnmaximizeFull"/>
   <action name="MaximizeVert"/>     
   <action name="MoveResizeTo">
      <x>-0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <width client="yes">1/2</width>
   </action>
</keybind>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created this thing, which is a more advanced version of semi-maximize left/right/up/down. Also available as a Gist here `https://gist.github.com/zrajm/3621cc90d9bc30d06bbe926fc8b2692a`

## Keybindings for Window Tiling

For the below code to work insert it into the  section of your Openbox config. On Lubuntu it's called `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`. To reload the config after modifying it, you can either logout and login again, or run the command:

```
openbox --reconfigure
```

## How to Use It

Windows key + arrows: Resizes a window to half-screen. Combinations (e.g. Windows-Up followed by Windows-Left) can be used to resize to quarter-screen. Twice in the same direction (e.g. Windows-Right + Windows-Right) will maximize a window.

Window-Space: Toggles window decorations/borders (i.e. switches title bar, close button etc on/off). For this to be really screen maximizing you might want to also remove the one pixel border around each window, but this can only be done by putting `<keepBorder>no</keepBorder>` inside the `<theme>` of your openbox config. (It cannot be toggled for each individual window, unfortunately, at least not on Openbox 3.6.1.) Even with decorations turned off the usual keybindings Alt-F4 to close, Alt + mouse to drag around etc. still works.

## Quirks

Terminal (and maybe some other?) windows are resized in steps (the step size depends on the size of the font used in the window). These windows may not completely fill out the expected part of the screen, leaving gaps between windows. The below code tries to minimize the problem in two ways:

First: I scale terminal windows to 50.5% of the screen, rather than the expected 50%. (Well, actually I use the fraction '101/200' for syntax reasons, but you get the point.) This seems to work for me (causing my terminals to ever so slightly go outside the screen sometimes). Search for `x-terminal-emulator' below to see how this is done.

Second: To cut down the annoyance of the gaps between the windows, I place the windows so that any gaps appear along the edges of the screen, rather than between the windows. The hope is that this will cause the least distraction if you have set your window manager to raise windows as the mouse pointer enter them. By having no gap between the windows, there's no risk that you'll accidentally enter a background window (causing that to suddenly raise to the top) as you move the pointer between windows. (The drawback is that, if you're in the habit of shoving the pointer to the edge of the screen to get it out of the way, you might instead accidentally raise a background window that way.) There's really no way of solving this, only trade offs. If you don't like my preferred behavior there are comments in the code below to help you change it. Simply search for comments containing 'at screen edge', and enable the commented code just before that (the change needs to be done in four places, one for each arrow key).

```xml
    <!-- Windows-Space: Toggle window decorations. -->
    <keybind key="W-space">
      <action name="ToggleDecorations"/>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Windows-Left: Left half of screen. -->
    <keybind key="W-Left">
      <action name="Raise"/>
      <action name="If"><query target="default">
        <maximized>no</maximized>
        <maximizedvertical>yes</maximizedvertical>
      </query><then>
        <!-- Only vertically maximized: Maximize completely. -->
        <action name="Maximize"/>
      </then><else>
        <action name="If"><query target="default">
          <maximizedhorizontal>no</maximizedhorizontal>
        </query><then>
          <!-- Not horizontally maximized: Maximize vertically. -->
          <action name="Maximize"><direction>vertical</direction></action>
        </then></action>
        <!-- Halve window width. -->
        <action name="Unmaximize"><direction>horizontal</direction></action>
        <action name="If">
          <query target="default"><name>x-terminal-emulator</name></query>
          <then><action name="MoveResizeTo"><width client="yes">101/200</width></action></then>
          <else><action name="MoveResizeTo"><width client="yes">1/2</width></action></else>
        </action>
        <!-- Put on left half of screen. -->
        <action name="MoveResizeTo">
          <x client="yes">-50%</x>     <!-- right edge at screen midpoint -->
          <!--x client="yes">0</x-->   <!-- left  edge at screen edge     -->
        </action>
      </else></action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Windows-Right: Right half screen. -->
    <keybind key="W-Right">
      <action name="Raise"/>
      <action name="If"><query target="default">
        <maximized>no</maximized>
        <maximizedvertical>yes</maximizedvertical>
      </query><then>
        <!-- Only vertically maximized: Maximize completely. -->
        <action name="Maximize"/>
      </then><else>
        <action name="If"><query target="default">
          <maximizedhorizontal>no</maximizedhorizontal>
        </query><then>
          <!-- Not horizontally maximized: Maximize vertically. -->
          <action name="Maximize"><direction>vertical</direction></action>
        </then></action>
        <!-- Halve window width. -->
        <action name="Unmaximize"><direction>horizontal</direction></action>
        <action name="If">
          <query target="default"><name>x-terminal-emulator</name></query>
          <then><action name="MoveResizeTo"><width client="yes">101/200</width></action></then>
          <else><action name="MoveResizeTo"><width client="yes">1/2</width></action></else>
        </action>
        <!-- Put on right half of screen. -->
        <action name="MoveResizeTo">
          <x client="yes">50%</x>      <!-- left  edge at screen midpoint -->
          <!--x client="yes">-0</x-->  <!-- right edge at screen edge     -->
        </action>
      </else></action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Windows-Up: Upper half of screen. -->
    <keybind key="W-Up">
      <action name="Raise"/>
      <action name="If"><query target="default">
        <maximized>no</maximized>
        <maximizedhorizontal>yes</maximizedhorizontal>
      </query><then>
        <!-- Only horizontally maximized: Maximize completely. -->
        <action name="Maximize"/>
      </then><else>
        <action name="If"><query target="default">
          <maximizedvertical>no</maximizedvertical>
        </query><then>
          <!-- Not vertically maximized: Maximize horizontally. -->
          <action name="Maximize"><direction>horizontal</direction></action>
        </then></action>
        <!-- Halve window height. -->
        <action name="Unmaximize"><direction>vertical</direction></action>
        <action name="If">
          <query target="default"><name>x-terminal-emulator</name></query>
          <then><action name="MoveResizeTo"><height client="yes">101/200</height></action></then>
          <else><action name="MoveResizeTo"><height client="yes">1/2</height></action></else>
        </action>
        <!-- Put on upper half of screen. -->
        <action name="MoveResizeTo">
          <y client="yes">-50%</y>     <!-- bottom edge at screen midpoint -->
          <!--x client="yes">0</x-->   <!-- top    edge at screen edge     -->
        </action>
      </else></action>
    </keybind>
    <!-- Windows-Down: Lower half of screen. -->
    <keybind key="W-Down">
      <action name="Raise"/>
      <action name="If"><query target="default">
        <maximized>no</maximized>
        <maximizedhorizontal>yes</maximizedhorizontal>
      </query><then>
        <!-- Only horizontally maximized: Maximize completely. -->
        <action name="Maximize"/>
      </then><else>
        <action name="If"><query target="default">
          <maximizedvertical>no</maximizedvertical>
        </query><then>
          <!-- Not vertically maximized: Maximize horizontally. -->
          <action name="Maximize"><direction>horizontal</direction></action>
        </then></action>
        <!-- Halve window height. -->
        <action name="Unmaximize"><direction>vertical</direction></action>
        <action name="If">
          <query target="default"><name>x-terminal-emulator</name></query>
          <then><action name="MoveResizeTo"><height client="yes">101/200</height></action></then>
          <else><action name="MoveResizeTo"><height client="yes">1/2</height></action></else>
        </action>
        <!-- Put on lower half of screen. -->
        <action name="MoveResizeTo">
          <y client="yes">50%</y>      <!-- top    edge at screen midpoint -->
          <!--x client="yes">-0</x-->  <!-- bottom edge at screen edge     -->
        </action>
      </else></action>
    </keybind>
```