# Is it possible in lxqt (lubuntu 22.04) to maximize-left/right as in LXDE (lubuntu 18.04)?

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, lxqt

In LXDE (Lubuntu 18.04), I was used to vertically maximize a window to any of the two halves of the screen using the keybinding Win+left or Win+right as detailed in this answer (https://askubuntu.com/a/1240081/1582728). Is this type of action still available in lxqt (Lubuntu 22.04)?

Comment: The <Super> key is used to open the menu; which caused some prior usage to get lost; this was done many cycles ago & it's all *hazy* for me now, but our current shortcuts here (*with mention of stack order*) - https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html details of changes found here - https://phab.lubuntu.me/T59   As I recall the dual-use of SUPER caused issues but T59   There's another place with details/attempts to make it work but I forget where..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @guiverc answer, I've found the solution: it was sufficient to disable the keybindings of the menu `Super_L`. Now everything works fine.
From the [Lubuntu manual](https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/F/keyboard_shortcuts.html#openbox-keyboard-shortcuts)

> Global-keys will take preference over openbox bindings. If a key is
> used in Global-keys, it will not work in Openbox keyboard shortcuts.
> For example if the W(indows) key opens the LXQT application menu
> (equivalent of the windows start menu) in Global-keys, Openbox
> commands like window resizing (W + arrow keys) will not work
> correctly. Keep this in mind when using and editing keyboard
> shortcuts.

Exactly what I was looking for (likely a RTFM answer...).